# Prevent PreferenceFragment from writing default preferences to SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

Current behavior of `PreferenceFragment`: Upon first display on screen `PreferenceFragment` writes to associated `SharedPreferences` all default values defined in `PreferenceScreen` XML resource. I tested this couple times and PreferenceFragment as well as PreferenceActivity writes all preferences defaults to SharedPreferences when user opens Settings activity, even if he immediately close it without touching anything.

Problem: When in the next version of my app I decide to change some default user preferences, they will not apply to the devices where user at least once opened app preferences, because `PreferenceFragment` wrote all default values to `SharedPreferences`. I know that I can reapply new default values by overwriting all values in `SharedPreferences`, not only default, but user chosen too. But resetting user preferences in app update is completely unacceptable. So the problem is that we cant distinguish when some particular preference was set explicity by user or its just default preference written by `PreferenceFragment` upon first display on screen.

What I want: If the user explicity set some preference, whatever he has chosen, I should not touch this with my updated app defaults, even if user choice is coincides with my old default. But if user was not explicity chose preference I want that my new default preferences start working for him with app update.

So: How to prevent write of default preferences values by `PreferenceFragment` to associated SharedPreferences?

Comment: if the user did not change anything with particular preference it will not appear in the preference xml file where all the values are stored

Comment: @pskink I tested this couple times and PreferenceFragment as well as PreferenceActivity commit all preferences defaults to SharedPreferences when user first time opens  preference window. I was surprised, when noticed it

Comment: `... and PreferenceActivity commit all preferences defaults to SharedPreferences ... ` you mean the physical file `/data/data/your.package/ shared_prefs/your.package_preferences.xml` is populated with the default values? for a test dump that file, then add some new Preference, dump the file again, change that preference and dump that file again

Comment: @pskink I have tested this on many devices, with different Android versions, for example right now I have Cyanogen device with root, and before reply to you I even tested it again. Deleted `shared_prefs/my.package_preferences.xml`, opened Settings window, that is just system PreferenceFragment with single call to `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);`, and after I closed app, I can see all prefs defined in my R.xml.prefs committed to `shared_prefs/my.package_preferences.xml`.

Comment: @pskink I updated my question with link to source of `TwoStatePreference` where commit occurs on initialization time.

Comment: hmmm, so it seems that it has changed, i can swear i didnt see the defaults if you didnt touch the preference

Answer (score 1):

After studying sources I found a way to achieve requested behavior.

The only place where real write to `SharedPreferences` occurs it's bunch of `persist[Type]` methods in `Preference` class. And subclasses of `Preference` usually call `persist[Type]` method only in single internal method, that has similar structure across all subclasses. For example, method from `TwoStatePreference`, that is superclass of `ChekBoxPreference` and `SwitchPreference`:

```
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    boolean changed = this.mChecked != checked;
    if(changed || !this.mCheckedSet) {
        this.mChecked = checked;
        this.mCheckedSet = true;
        this.persistBoolean(checked);
        if(changed) {
            this.notifyDependencyChange(this.shouldDisableDependents());
            this.notifyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Next, `setChecked` method of `TwoStatePreference` is called in about five other methods, and two of these calls can produce default value to be committed to `SharedPreferences`. Here is first:

```
@Override
protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
    setChecked(restoreValue ? getPersistedBoolean(mChecked)
            : (Boolean) defaultValue);
}
```

And second:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (state == null || !state.getClass().equals(SavedState.class)) {
        // Didn't save state for us in onSaveInstanceState
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        return;
    }

    SavedState myState = (SavedState) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(myState.getSuperState());
    setChecked(myState.checked);
}
```

And here is the solution, custom class, that subclasses SwitchPreferenceCompat and preventing commit in two above calls:

```
public class MySwitchPref extends SwitchPreferenceCompat
{
    private boolean mAllowPersist;

    @Override
    protected boolean persistBoolean(boolean value) {
        if (mAllowPersist) {
            return super.persistBoolean(value);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue,
            Object defaultValue) {
        mAllowPersist = false;
        super.onSetInitialValue(restoreValue, defaultValue);
        mAllowPersist = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        mAllowPersist = false;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        mAllowPersist = true;
    }

    public MySwitchPref(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public MySwitchPref(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public MySwitchPref(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MySwitchPref(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

You should replace your SwitchPreferenceCompat declaration in xml PreferenceScreen to this subclass and all should work, I have tested it. And if you use other then SwitchPreference types of preferences, you as well should similarly subclass and override their behavior.

***Beware: This solution relies upon internal realization of current,  com.android.support:preference-v7:23.4.0 library. It might change with future releases, so if you use other library version, or use non support implementation you should look in to source, and ensure there is no other calls to persist values in SharedPreferences except that two, that I overriden. As well if you use other subclasses of Preference, not only SwitchPreference, you should check for other calls to persist values in SharedPreferences.***